# Passing space in parameters to php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table name "User" writen in MySQL with the fields: UserID, UserName, Password, eMail, DisplayName, Score, timeStamp. The field UserID is int AUTO_INCREMENT and time stamp is dateTime. I'm trying to insert values into the table using php file. This is my php file:

```
mysql_connect("mysql.1freehosting.com","u948577195_uname","p7CraCuRAw");

mysql_select_db("u948577195_dbnam");

$uName = $_GET['uname'];
$pass = $_GET['password'];
$mail = $_GET['email'];
$disName = $_GET['disnam'];
$date = $_GET['dt'];

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO User
VALUES ('$uName', '$pass', '$mail', '$disName', 0, '$date')");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

$output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();

?>
```

I activate the file using this connection string:

```
http://pickupfriend.fulba.com/android_project/query3.php?uname=Test&password=p1&email=ml&disnam=Test&dt=21:12:30 2014-07-07
```

I have a space between the seconds and the year in the date, is it OK? After I run the connection string I receive this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u948577195/public_html/android_project/query3.php on line 13
```

What am I doing wrong? How to correct my connection string?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: btw, you're vulnerable to a SQL injection attack with this code.

Comment: Also changed the credentials of db server if u posted correct one here :)

Comment: If this is on the public internet, you're exposing yourself to **extreme** risk. You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) so you don’t create any more severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like the one you have here. Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications, it's being removed from PHP. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and is a safer way to compose queries. `$_GET` data **never** goes directly in a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link shows that you are getting the parameters wrong in the `$_GET` part.

Hence you must delete this line as it's not php

```
INSERT INTO [USER]
VALUES ('$uName', '$pass', '$mail', '$disName', 0, '$date')
```

Change your code as as below.

```
mysql_connect("mysql.1freehosting.com","u948577195_uname","p7CraCuRAw");

mysql_select_db("u948577195_dbnam");

$uName = $_GET['uname'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$mail = $_GET['mail'];
$disName = $_GET['disName'];
$date = $_GET['date'];

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO User VALUES ('$uName', '$pass', '$mail', '$disName', 0, '$date')");
if (!$sql) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}
mysql_close();
```

And your are not fetching anything within your query, if your aim is to see all add this before `mysql_close()`

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM User');
if (!$query) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    die($message);
}
$output = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) !== false) {
   $output[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: You didn't change anything here.

Comment: i changed `password` -> `pass`, `email` -> `mail`, `disnam` -> `disName`, `dt` -> `date`, check the question again.

Comment: yeah, that's another bug in the code. But not the crashing one.

Comment: Still needs a lot more help before a) it's MySQL, right now SQL Server, and b) won't expose your server to being cracked wide open in seconds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new in this. All I want is to insert new row in a table. Can you give me a hand? I changed the php file and the connection string.

Comment: @itzickbinder what are your columns in your User table? Also you need to change the part i've mentioned above also.

Comment: These are the columns: UserID, UserName, Password, eMail, DisplayName, Score, timeStamp. but UserID is AUTO_INCREMENT and I don't have to insert value in it

Comment: then your query should work if you have changed your buggy parts.

Comment: But I'm getting that error message: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/u948577195/public_html/android_project/query3.php on line 16 null

Comment: But what if I don't want to see the entire table? Just insert a new row and thats it?

Comment: remove the below part then. check the edit, if you get any errors paste here.

Answer (score 1):

And what do you expect to happen?

```
INSERT INTO [USER]
VALUES ('$uName', '$pass', '$mail', '$disName', 0, '$date')
```

That is NOT php! You forgot to use it in a query or something.